# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples. Based on Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster

Tags: python

I want to split the data, but I get an error

```
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(train_df, test_df, test_size=0.3, random_state=17)
```

train_df:

```
Age       Fare        PClass_1    PClass_2  ...
22.0      7.2500      NaN         NaN       ... 
38.0      71.2833     NaN         NaN       ...
26.0      7.9250      NaN         NaN       ...
...       ...         ...         ...
```

test_df:

```
Age     Fare       PClass_1     PClass_2    ...
34.5    7.8292     NaN          NaN         ...
47.0    7.0000     NaN          NaN         ...
2.0     9.6875     NaN          NaN         ...
...     ...        ...          ...
```

I need to make a `DecisionTreeClassifier`. To do this, I need to split the data using `train_test_split`, but I can't. I also tried to throw out extra lines using `drop`, but it doesn't happen the way I need it. What is the problem?

Comment: What error message do you get? 

Apart from this, you don't pass the proper arguments to the function. It should be (X, y) with X a dataframe with all variables except the target values, and y a series with only the target values. In case you get an error not on the train_test_split function but after, on training your model, that may come from this.

Comment: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5346, 2508]

Comment: You are passing the training and test datasets, when you should be passing a DataFrame with the training features (_X_, i.e. the training set without the `Survived` column) and a Series (or array) with the target (_y_, the `Survived` column).

Comment: BTW, where did you get 5346 samples? There's 891 passengers in the training set from Kaggle.

Comment: This is the number of variables

Comment: I do not know why there are 5346 samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation of train_test_split() says, the arguments are "sequence of **indexables with same length / shape[0]**.
Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes."

Why must they be the same length? Because `train_test_split` has been written for users that want to perform :

- unsupervised learning (with no target values, only variables)
- or supervised learning, so they deal with on one hand, variables, and on the other hand, corresponding target values. This is the case you are dealing with (Titanic is classification, hence supervised).

Here, the problem is that you pass as arguments 2 dataframes that dont have the same length. They should though, since they are supposed to be, respectively, variables and corresponding target values.

By the way, where did you get these 2 dataframes? Because their names show that there's already been a splitting there.

In fact, they can have been created by the following code:

```
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df)
```

See what `train_test_split` does?

- If you pass 1 dataframe (or series, or list, or array), it will split it into 2 dataframe (or series, etc) into a "train" df and a "test" df, with the proportion set with the `test_size argument`. This can be used for unsupervised learning (not labeled data = no target value).
- if you pass 2 dataframes (or, etc...), it will consider that they are linked:  the first contains the variables and the second the target value. So it will split these 2 df in a "parallel" way, if that makes sense (see example below).

So how to get the result you want?

You must pass 2 arguments:

- a dataframe `X` that contains all the variables but not the target value (i.e. not the "survived" variable)
- a series `y` that contains only the target values (= the variable "survived").

And by definition these 2 objects have same length.

Hence:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
```

As a result:

- `X_train` and `y_train` have same length (and y_train target value corresponds of course to X_train variables)
- same for `X_test` and `y_test`.

If it still not clear maybe this can help. Under the hood, train_test_split works like this:

"OK, the data scientist gave me 2 datasets A and B. I select 30% (from the parameter `test_size=0.3`) of the rows in dataset A. let's call it `A_test`.

The 70% remaining rows, I put them in another dataset, `A_train`.

Now I do the same for dataset B, and to be relevant, I select for `B_test` the **rows that have the same index as in `A_test`**.

Of course, in `B_train`, the rows will have the same indexes as in `A_train`.

And finally I return `A_train, A_test, B_train, B_test`. Job done!"